# How to extract the parameter value from the REST Request?

Tags: rest

I am passing the request Add MSISDN Request to hit the resource path.

Method: POST

```
{
"msisdn":"xxxx",
"carrier": "xxxx"
}
```

I am getting success response which indicates that "it is created"

Now I want to verify this by GET Call. It is retrieving the added MSISDN. But i need to add the assertion that the passed MSISDN on the previous request is being retrieved or not..

For that i need to extract the MSISDN value from the first Method. Is there any to extract the parameter from the REST Request?

Comment: Of course, you can extract query parameters from the post request. But how to do that depends on your framework.

Answer (score 0):

your service is returning a json then you need to deserialise it.

You can easly do that in c# by using

```
public static string ToJson<T>(T instance)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var tempStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(tempStream, instance);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tempStream.ToArray(), 0, Convert.ToInt32(tempStream.Length));
    }
}

public static T FromJson<T>(string json)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var tempStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        return (T)serializer.ReadObject(tempStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any link how to deserialise it?